# Bad operand types for binary operator '| |' first type: int; second type: int. What does this mean?

Tags: java

When trying to compile i'm being given the error message: Bad operand types for binary operator  '| |' first type: int; second type: int.

This is the code i have written, although it isn't finished.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        int squareSize = BIO.getInt();

        for(int row = 0; row == squareSize; row++)
        {
            if (row = 1 || row = squareSize)
        { for(int stars = 0; stars <=squareSize; stars++)
            System.out.print("*");

    }    
}
```

Please could you tell me what this means and how i can fix it?

Comment: row == 1 || row == squareSize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (row = 1 || row = squareSize)
```

`=` is an *assignment* operator, not a equality/relational operator.

I think you want `==`:

```
if (row == 1 || row == squareSize)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `if (row = 1 || row = squareSize)` to `if (row == 1 || row == squareSize)`.

What is happening now is you are doing assignments to the variable row and then ORing the numbers together, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be confused between `=` and `==` operators :

```
if (row == 1 || row == squareSize)
```

`=` is used to assignate a value to a variable, whereas the second is used to process a logical comparison between two variables.

Answer (score 0):

need to use == not =

```
if (row == 1 || row == squareSize)
```